# Owl carousel jumpt to specific index after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using **owl carousel 2**. I have a few buttons on my page. When clicking on one of those buttons there will be an AJAX call. From that ajax call comes an image id. I compare that image id to one in the owl carousel and then want to jump to the matching slide.

However, whatever I try the index number returns `0`. So owl always jumps to the very first image. I tried several things but I just can't get it to work.

**My list with buttons**

```html
<div class="spo-list">
  <div class="spo-item" data-image="47059110">Dunkelrot</div>
  <div class="spo-item" data-image="47059111">Rot</div>
</div>
```

**My slider**

```html
<div class="thumbnail-slider-container"> 
  <div id="thumbnailSlider" class="thumbnail-slider owl-carousel"> 
    <div data-imageid="47059110"><img src="image" /></div>
    <div data-imageid="47059111"><img src="image" /></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**The code**

```
$('.spo-item').on('click', function(){
  var img = $(this).data('image')
  var url = link-to-page
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success:function(data) {
      var next_id = data.image_id // the ID that comes from the call like '47059110' 
      var next_slide = var next_slide = $('#thumbnailSlider').find('div[data-imageid="'+next_id+'"]').closest('.owl-item').index()
      console.log(next_slide)
      $('#thumbnailSlider').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [next_slide, 300, true]); 
      // this jumps to first image since "next_slide" always is 0
    }
  });
});
```

I just can't see what's wrong with getting the index. I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216000/owl-carousel-jump-to-a-slide-with-an-certain-id) as a reference.

Anybody an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is correct. Could you post the data object you get on the success callback? I think if you always get the same index: 0. Then you always get the image_id for the 1st one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an answer to the problem! 
The problem was that I tried to get the index of the wrong element. Owl carousel wraps every item in a div called `owl-item`. So when you try to get the index number of an item then it will always be index 0 since there's just one item in the wrapped element. The actual html looks like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail-slider-container"> 
  <div id="thumbnailSlider" class="thumbnail-slider owl-carousel"> 
    <div class="owl-item"><div data-imageid="47059110"><img src="image" /></div></div>
    <div class="owl-item"><div data-imageid="47059111"><img src="image" /></div></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

So to get the correct index you need to use:

```
var next_slide = $('#thumbnailSlider').find('div[data-imageid="'+next_id+'"]').closest('.owl-item').index()
```